# Installation of Broadcom driver has failed on a Dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

I just installed 11.10 on my inspiron 1545 laptop. When I was running it off my flash drive the driver "Broadcom STA Wireless Driver" installed fine and I could use my wifi. After I installed it onto the computer the driver could not install it just says

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
>   Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

I tried looking for a fix but nothing i could find worked with the new ubuntu.
The log says:

```
2011-10-22 22:42:18,605 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2011-10-22 22:42:18,636 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2011-10-22 22:42:18,691 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Some user's are having problem after and upgrade to ubuntu 11.10 so try this

```
apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

if this doesn't work try this :

- Enter Software Center;
- wrote "bcm", and found all the broadcomm related things and checked to erase them;
- restart;
- went again to "hardware instalation" and checked the broadcom to install.
- restart;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/511379) on Launchpad, in which there are various solutions to this problem.